# Insert data into DB once all fields have been validated - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I wonder if you can help me please. I am passing data from a html form into a MySQL DB using PHP. All fields have been validated but I want it to validate all the data before any of it goes into the DB.

For example, if there are not enough characters entered in the 'name' field it will tell the user, however if the email address is correctly validated it then inserts the data into the DB. How would I go about doing that?

```
    // check the length of 'name' field if between 2 and 50 characters

    if ((strlen($name) < 2 || strlen($name) > 50)) {
        echo "The name is invalid, must be between 2 and 50 chearacters.";
        exit;

    }

    echo "</br>";

    // check field name contains numbers
    if (preg_match('#[0-9]#',$name)){ 

        echo 'The name is invalid, its contains numbers. Please go back and try again.';
    }  

    echo "</br>";

    // Check if email is valid. If not tell the user it is invalid

    $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 
    if (!preg_match($regex, $emailaddress)) {
            echo "Invalid email address. Please go back and try again.";
    }

  // insert the data from the registration form into the DB  
  mysql_query("INSERT into customers 
      (cs_name, cs_emailaddress) 
      VALUES
  (
  '".$name."', '".$emailaddress."',
  )
  ")
  or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make the script die before mysql_query() is called, or you create a $isValid variable initially true that you set to false when something goes wrong. And you put a condition before mysql_query:

```
if ($isValid === true)
{
    mysql_query(...
}
```

Comment: Ok, do you mean set $isValid to false after each validation statement?

Comment: I'm not too sure on how to go about doing that?

Comment: A comment is too short to write you the correct code. 
But if you don't know how to create a variable and use it, don't try to modify this code. This is dangerous.

Comment: I did something similar and use an array variable. If the conditional statements were not true then it was stored in the variable as follows: echo $errors['name'] = "The name is invalid, must be between 2 and 50 chearacters.";. This was then checked on the insert query if something was added to the array, if nothing then data was inserted into the DB.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using jquery field validation. There is a function `valid()` in jquery using which you can ensure whether your fields are all valid.

If `valid()` returns true then carry out your mysql operation. You can use ajax call incase it is needed.

Comment: Thanks I will try that I've validated it by PHP.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. If the user disables Javascript on his browser, you will insert not valid data in your database !